# How to check if the characters in a given string can spell the word in another String using this method?

Tags: java

```
public static String removeChar(String tiles, char ch) {
   String removedWord = "";
   int single = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length();i++) {
     if(tiles.charAt(i) != ch || single == 1) {
       removedWord = removedWord + tiles.charAt(i);
     }else if(single == 0) {
       removedWord = removedWord + "";
       single++;
     }
   }return removedWord;

 }
```

I have to create a method that can check whether the characters in a string can spell a word from another string, for example

- canSpell("WQXOACW","COW")   --> true
- canSpell("WQXOACW","PIG")   --> false
- canSpell("","PIG")          --> false
- canSpell("WESCQSI","")      --> true
- canSpell("","")             --> true

I have to use the removeChar method above. I cant use substrings. Please help, ive been working on this for days but can't figure it out

Comment: Which part you can't figure out? Why you want to use substrings? The removeChar method makes the whole task as easy as it can get.

Comment: I suggest thinking about how you would do this by hand. What steps do you take to check if "COW" can be spelled by the letters in "WQXOACW"? Describe these steps in English. For example, take the first letter in "COW" and check if it is in the string "WQXOACW". If it is, then remove it. Now take the second letter in "COW". Once you can clearly describe the steps, then try to write the code for those steps.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter - character set

Second parameter - word

You want to be loop through all the characters in the second parameter, then check whether the frequency of the current character being looped through is bigger than the frequency of the current character in the first parameter. If it is, then we know we don't have enough characters to construct that word.

For example, assume our character set is `WQXOACW` and the word to construct is `COW`. We go through every character in `COW`, and check how many times each character appears. `C` appears once. Then we check the frequency of `C` in the character set. In this case, it is also 1. If it was smaller, (e.g, 0) then we would know that we do not have enough characters create the word because we don't have enough of that character, so we return `false`.

```
public static boolean canSpell(String scrambled, String target) {
    int tlength = target.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < tlength; i++) {
        char c= target.charAt(i);
        if(frequency(target,c) > frequency(scrambled,c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public static int frequency(String scrambled, char c) {
    int l = scrambled.length();
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        s = s + (scrambled.charAt(i) == c ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Test Run**

```
canSpell("WQXOACW","COW") //true
canSpell("WQXOACW","CO") //true
canSpell("WQXOACW","COWWW") //false
```

To further optimize efficiency (in the above code, we happened to check the frequency of the same character if it appeared more than once), we can remove all duplicate letters in the string using the below method:

```
public String removeDuplicates(String input){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(!result.contains(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
            result += String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Spectric stated, to resolve this task the frequencies of characters in the string and the word should be compared.

It is convenient to calculate the frequency of characters using Java Stream API and then check the characters in the word to detect cases when a word character is missing or the count of a word character is greater than the calculated frequency:

```java
public static boolean canSpell(String scrambled, String word) {
    Map<Character, Integer> freqScrambled = scrambled
            .toLowerCase()
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.summingInt(c -> 1)));

    for (char wordChar : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        // wordChar is missing
        if (!freqScrambled.containsKey(wordChar)) { 
            return false;
        }
        // there are fewer wordChars in scrambled than in word
        if (freqScrambled.computeIfPresent(wordChar, (k, v) -> v - 1) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tests

```java
System.out.println(canSpell("abcdefgh", "bad"));     // true
System.out.println(canSpell("abcdefgh", "back"));    // false
System.out.println(canSpell("abcdefghijk", "dead")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.  As each character from word is found in the supply, set it to 0. If the supply is exhausted before the loop is complete, return false. To increase efficiency, stream operations are avoided and iterations are kept to a minimum.

```
List<String> testData = List.of("WQXOACW", "PIG", "",
        "PIG", "", "", "foobar", "", "counrts", "country", "wocxayw",
        "wow", "feoce", "coffee", "tactic", "cat");

for (int i = 0; i < testData.size(); i+= 2) {
    String letters = testData.get(i);
    String word = testData.get(i+1);
    System.out.printf("%10s -> %10s = %b%n",letters,word,
            canSpell(letters, word));
}
```

Prints

```
   WQXOACW ->        PIG = false
           ->        PIG = false
           ->            = true
    foobar ->            = true
   counrts ->    country = false
   wocxayw ->        wow = true
     feoce ->     coffee = false
    tactic ->        cat = true
```

The method

```
    
public static boolean canSpell(String letters, String word) {
    
    char[] lets = letters.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] wordChars = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    if (wordChars.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    outer:
    for (char c : wordChars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lets.length; i++) {
            if (c == lets[i]) {
                lets[i] = 0;
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```